# trying to show the full blog on a new html page after clicking on read more button in the blog card in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am working on a blogging website in Django.

I have a few blogs and I am loading them in the card from my database.My card has a **read more** button(To go to new HTML page and dynamically fetch the contents of the particular blog).

Instead of creating a new html page for every blog I am using a single html page to show the contents of the blog from the **read more** button clicked on card.

But I am getting the following error:
**Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/$']**

Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogs/
  Django Version:   2.2.6
  Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch
  Exception Value:
  Exception Location:   C:\django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in_reverse_with_prefix, line 673**

**Thanks alot in advance**

**models.py**

```
class blog(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES=(
    ("scholarship","Scholarship"),
        ("examination","Examination"),
        ("career","Career"),
        ("fellowship","Fellowship")
        )

blog_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_media',default="")
blog_title=models.CharField(max_length=300)
slug = models.SlugField( max_length=200, unique=True)
blog_type = models.CharField( max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="scholarship" )
blog_author_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
blog_content=models.CharField(max_length=5000)
publish_date=models.DateField()
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',views.index,name='home'),
path('blogs/',views.blogs,name='blogs'),
path('about/',views.about,name='about'),
path('admissions/',views.admissions,name='admissions'),
path( '<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail' ),]
```

**views.py**

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    #my model name is blog
    model = blog
    #this is the html page on which I want to show the single blog data
    template_name = 'buddyscholarship_html/post_detail.html'
```

**code for loading the dynamic data from Django in html in a CardView:**

```
{% for i in data %}
</div>
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title">{{i.blog_title}}</h5>
<p class="card-text">{{i.blog_type}}</p>
<p class="card-text">By:{{i.blog_author_name}}</p>
<p class="card-text">{{i.blog_content|truncatechars:100}}</p>
<h5 class="card-title">{{i.publish_date}}</h5>
<!-----read more button for each and every blog coming from the database---------->
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' blog.slug  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a></div>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `i.slug` not `blog.slug`

```
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' i.slug  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a></div>
```

Comment: @umairnsr87 Feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) also if it worked.

Comment: I cannot accept the answer.It will take about 15 points to accept the answer and I do not have that much amout.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above answer one another method is define a get absoulute method in your models as follows and call it in your templates as `<a href="{{i.get_absolute_url}}"....`.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' blog.slug  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a></div>
```

Your problem should be solved after using i.slug instead of blog.slug but this is not the good approach here,you should use get_absolute_url method in this case.

```
<a href="{{i.get_absolute_url}}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a></div>
```

To implement this:
In your models.py inside your Model class add this method something like this:

```
from django.urls import reverse
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```